# Not loading whole title

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, load, title

In my [Blog](http://urstrulyvijay.blogspot.in/2016/06/green-apple-is-best-fruit-to-eat-in-all.html) not able to load the whole title of the post. The below image is my problem and not able to load the whole title of the post. But i don't know which code should i make to show the full post of the title.

[image: this]

The full code of my blog is at this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6QlS6MmIckNcDRRTGI1MHpMN1k/view?usp=sharing)

The below is the some part of my code.

```
<div id="delatepubpost">
<script src="/feeds/posts/default/-/apple?alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=related_results_labels_thumbs&amp;max-results=8" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var currentposturl="http://urstrulyvijay.blogspot.in/2016/06/green-apple-is-best-fruit-to-eat-in-all.html";
var maxresults=4;
  var relatedpoststitle="<b>You might also like:</b>";
removeRelatedDuplicates_thumbs();
printRelatedLabels_thumbs();
</script><h3><b>You might also like:</b></h3><div style="clear: both;"><a style="text-decoration:none;margin:0 0px 0px 0;float:left;border:none;" href="http://urstrulyvijay.blogspot.com/2016/06/green-apple-is-best-fruit-to-eat-in-all.html"><div class="arrow-but"><img class="mugs-in" src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-JJuc88XOQvQ/V3S-Klsu5fI/AAAAAAAAAFk/Rdb1UgLmgN0UynNA_N1rExfNy37wxNdTwCKgB/s1600/greenapple.jpg"><br></div><div class="delate-post">green apple is best fruit to eat in...</div></a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to add some indentation and enters to make your code more readable

Comment: @sietse85 below is the code which i able to find through console and this is the full code of my blog https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6QlS6MmIckNcDRRTGI1MHpMN1k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: so you wan't to make the post title a link to the full post?

Comment: @sietse85 i want to show http://urstrulyvijay.blogspot.in/2016/06/green-apple-is-best-fruit-to-eat-in-all.html  which is appearing in my post like in the related widget as shown in the image i think you got me

Comment: I looks like it's the blogspot software that cuts your title... if this happens server-side you would need to fix it there.

Comment: @sietse85 any other way to do it with jquery or javascript ..? <script type="text/javascript">
var currentposturl="http://urstrulyvijay.blogspot.in/2016/06/green-apple-is-best-fruit-to-eat-in-all.html";
var maxresults=4;
  var relatedpoststitle="<b>You might also like:</b>";
removeRelatedDuplicates_thumbs();
printRelatedLabels_thumbs();
</script>

Comment: If the full visible title is in the DOM tree as well you could use javascript to make it happens. But if this related news is displayed on another article you can't use it. Best fix this server side. Maybe there is some setting in your blog that allows you to show more characters in related articles.

Comment: The "full code" that you posted doesn't contain the word "apple", so it isn't the code you think it is.  While I agree with @sietse85 that the server is truncating your title, could this be part of the problem?

Comment: Visiting your blog, I see the HTML that is being presented has: `<div class="delate-post">green apple is best fruit to eat in...</div>`. This measn that it is being truncated before it is presented to the browser. You will not be able to fix this with client-side scripting (javascript or jquery). You will need to review the blogspot theme or settings to determine how to have the full title presented.